# ReferenceError for 3rd party library used in jQuery plugin, on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I'm working on an app that uses a jQuery UI plugin, which in turn uses the Raphael library. Things work great on iOS and normal browsers, but on android I am getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: can't find variable Raphael
```

raised in this line of the init method of the jQuery UI plugin I wrote (jquery.ui.sketch.js):

```
var p = Raphael(el.attr("id"));
```

This is the head of my index.html that I'm using to mock-up my app:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/raphael.json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.sketch.js"></script>
```

And the body looks like:

```
<body id="home">
 ... a bunch of divs
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

            // ...jquery stuff that works fine

            // initialize sketch widget, FAILS HERE ON ANDROID:
            $('#paper').sketch({
                saved: function(e,ui){
                    savedDrawing = ui;
                    alert("saved JSON to a global variable 'savedDrawing'");
                },
                // these could be bound to an element if we want:
                startdrawing: function(){
                    console.log("figure started");
                },
                donedrawing: function(){
                    console.log("finished drawing");
                }
            });

</script>
```

I'm kind of stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is simply that Raphael doesn't support Android (or rather has no way of doing SVG). Duh. Apparently v3.0 browser has SVG support.